# items not appearing in ComboBox list C#

Tags: c#, combobox

i want a dropdown list of predetermined usernames where a user can select from,using combobox.The code below is not working.[Login Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wqrv.png)

```
    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Attendee");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("HOD");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Driver");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("FD");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is going to add the items *after* you have selected one, that's why it doesn't work. You can either move that code to the Form's constructor or use the designer (there's an Items property where you can add those items)

Comment: Is that a winform or a webform? At any rate you'll want to add those at page load.

Comment: Hi Camilo,thanks for reaching out but how do i "select one".Will you help me through, i'm just starting to learn c#.

Comment: @Mayhem50 looks like a Winform in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Double click your login form then put your code in the `Load` event handler. The event handler name is `YourFormName_Load` by default.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Attendee");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("HOD");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Driver");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("FD");
        }
    }
}
```